# How to make the link text change color instead of underlining when hovered over

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I have this menu I set up and it underlines when hovered over, but I would like it to change color, which is the default for my wordpress theme. The title, "BOLI STYLUS" changes color exactly like I want.

Here is the code for the title:

```
<hgroup>
                <h1 id="site-title"><span><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></span></h1>
                <h2 id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
            </hgroup>
```

Here is the menu:

[image: menu]

Here is the style.css code for it:

```
.header_nav ul{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    }

.header_nav ul li{
    display: inline;
    }

.header_nav ul li a{
    float: center; 
    padding: 10.5px 11px;
    }

.header_nav ul li a:hover, .menu ul li .current{
    color: #50a9cb;
    }
```

Here is the header.php code:

```
<div class="header_nav">
                <ul>

                            <li><a href="/pages/glifoptions">BOLI</a></li>      

                            <li><a href="/products/cosmonaut">BOLI+</a></li>

                            <li><a href="/pages/about-us">ABOUT US</a></li>

                            <li><a href="/pages/faq">FAQ</a></li>

                            <li><a href="/pages/press">PRESS</a></li>   

                    <li><a href="/cart">YOUR CART (0)</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: It should change color on hover http://jsfiddle.net/64Wsq/. I'm guessing it's getting overridden by some other CSS. Where is the rest of your CSS ? The snapshot doesn't match the CSS posted.

Comment: What is `float: center`? Not in CSS2.1. Also, color in `a:hover` should work—what is the question here?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder I'm using a child theme, the parent theme .css is too large to post.

Comment: Then inspect it in firebug or developer tools and take a look at what css is overriding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule, and replace **XXXXXX** with your desired color. I assume you want to keep the styles in the same spirit, i.e. have the selected item also have the same style as when you hover it.

```
.header_nav ul li a:hover, .menu ul li .current
{
    color: #XXXXXX; /* replace with real value */ text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you showed already *does* color the text when you hover it.  It also, however, underlines it.  To change that add text-decoration: none; like I did below.

```
.header_nav ul li a{
    float: center;
    padding: 10.5px 11px;
    **text-decoration: none;**
    }
```

For the complete code, see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8KPcy/1/

Comment: Take a look at his screen shot.